# Setting subclass property results in an unexpected error

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, subclass, setter, matlab-class

I have an object that has been instantiated as the class `NIRFlex` which inherits from the [serial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/serial-port-object.html) class. When I attempt to assign a value of `0` to the property `Text_mode` from the command line:

```
>> N.Text_mode = 0
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error using serial/subsasgn (line 146) 
The name 'Text_mode' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'serial port objects'.
```

My class definition, constructor, and set method are as follows:

```
classdef NIRFlex < serial

    properties
        Text_mode
    end
    methods
        function obj = NIRFlex(port)
            obj = obj@serial(port);
        end

        function obj = set.Text_mode(obj,mode)
            if (mode == 1)||(mode == 2)
                obj.Text_mode = mode;
            else
                error('Invalid Text Mode');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If I remove the `set` method I can assign any arbitrary value I'd like to the `Text_mode` property at the command line but I need to ensure that the value entered is only `1` or `2`.

I reviewed the [Subclasses of Built-In Types with Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/built-in-subclasses-with-properties.html) document @ MathWorks but could not find an answer.

Comment: It's interesting that it's actually the `error` command generating that error. Funny. Removing the `error` command or replacing it with anything else will make the code work. This reference https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example-representing-structured-data.html#f2-74243 covers property set method with an 'if-else-error' structure but for non-inherited classes only.

Comment: @Yvon That is very strange. I removed the `error` command and it seems to work fine. If i replace `error` with a simple `disp()` command everything works so long as the argument passed to the set method is numeric, otherwise the same error returns. I am thoroughly perplexed!

Comment: If you set up a breakpoint and look at the code that throws the error (`subsasgn`), there's a try-catch block which throws that error message no matter what error is generated in your set method. Basically your error message is elevated to the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only confusing aspect of this problem is that you don't see your custom error message, but instead some other one generated by the `serial` class.

The reason this happens is because of the following code in `serial.subsasgn`, which gets executed in cases such as objects inheriting from `serial`:

```matlab
    catch aException
        try
            Obj = isetfield(Obj, prop1, Value);
        catch %#ok<CTCH>
            throw(localFixError(aException));
        end
    end
```

As you can see, MATLAB initially tries to set the `Value` of `prop1` (`0` and `Text_mode`, respectively), then your internal class throws an error, which is being caught by `subsasgn`'s `catch`, and replaced by the `aException` that was generated earlier and has a different reason.

I can suggest a couple of options:

- In your `set` method, if validation fails, instead of throwing an error, issue a warning and set the value to some default value or just mention that it wasn't modified from whatever it was before. This way you workaround MATLAB's "[error swallowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding)" mechanism.
- Contact MATLAB and ask them to fix this (i.e. make the internal exception reason visible as well).